# Does Raspbian mirror has a problem updating or is something wrong with bzip2 apt-get method

Tags: raspbian, apt

I get this error while running `sudo apt-get update`

```
Hit http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy InRelease
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy InRelease
Hit http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy/main armhf Packages
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org wheezy/main Translation-en
Get:1 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org wheezy/main armhf Packages [7379 kB]
100% [1 Packages 7379 kB/7379 kB 100%]Failed to exec method /usr/lib/apt/methods/bzip2
E: Method bzip2 has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process bzip2 returned an error code (100)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/bzip2 did not start correctly
```

What can it be? This is what I have in my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to translate those errors to English?

Comment: @Jivings My edit for that is pending ...

Comment: I run `RaspBMC` and it contains `deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Did you run `apt-get upgrade` first? Looks like it's an error with your mirrorlist.

Comment: upgrade doensn't return any error. i've also tried clean with no success

Comment: Can you show us a dump of your mirrorlist file?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4059495

Comment: any idea ? i tried: apt-get clean, removing one line at a time form the sources and running update.checked methods/ folder and i noticed that in ls bzip2 was white while others where green. did a chmod +x on it. still no success

Comment: first of all, prepends your command with `LANG=C` to disable your locales and get English error messages. It would be good if you could then update the question with English error messages. Secondly please check `dmesg` command output to see if there is no traces about segfaults. Also use `df` to check if you have space left on your disks.

Comment: Also check if `bzip2` command is working OK. Try compressing some random file and then decompress it.

Comment: i found this in `dmesg` `[28765.227866] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): ext4_iget:3939: inode #7937: comm find: bogus i_mode (72157)` it was also suggested on raspberry [forum](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=22935&p=215753#p215753) to reinstall apt packages manually `sudo wget http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg4.12_0.9.7.6+rpi1_armhf.deb
sudo wget http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.9.7.6+rpi1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libapt-pkg4.12_0.9.7.6+rpi1_armhf.deb apt_0.9.7.6+rpi1_armhf.deb` but this lead to some other errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it was a filesystem issue! I ended up repairing the FS in ubuntu with `fsck -y /dev/sdb` and then reinstalling apt manualy as [`plugwash`](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=215248#p215248) from RaspberryPi Forum suggested

```
sudo wget http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/libapt-pkg4.12_0.9.7.6+rpi1_armhf.deb
sudo wget http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.9.7.6+rpi1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libapt-pkg4.12_0.9.7.6+rpi1_armhf.deb apt_0.9.7.6+rpi1_armhf.deb
sudo apt-get update
```